# hostname is not set from DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, dhclient, systemd-networkd

I am using netplan to configure my wired interface via DHCP:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
```

I uninstalled dhclient and installed dhcpcd and even after running netplan apply, I cannot get the hostname (now via dhcpcd -U eno1).

If I manually do dhcpcd eno1 (before requesting the lease information), I can see the hostname.

Does networkd support using dhcpcd as the backend for dhcp leases?  I presume that networkd must be using its internal DHCP client?

All I really want is to get the hostname for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname can be retrieved via netplan ip leases .  It appears that it outputs the contents of a file residing in /run/systemd/netif/leases/<#>.

There is a field, HOSTNAME, that can be consumed.  It appears systemd / netplan are indicating this may change in the future, but once the hostname is retrieved, it can be set in the normal means.

```
hostname -b $(grep "HOSTNAME=" $(find /run/systemd/netif/leases -type f) | head -1 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
```